# How to retrieve static resource from backup

Tags: static-resources, backup

Apparently a co-worker accidentally overwrote a static resource zip file.  I do weekly backups.  Is it possible to retrieve past static resources from a zip file?

Comment: Is the weekly back from the Data Export function or are you backing up metadata explicitly?

Comment: I have weekly data export backups.  The good news is that I was able to get the missing static resource from the partial sandbox I made earlier in the week.  What should I do to have backups of the static resources.  I want to have backups of them if possible.

Answer (score 3):

The Weekly/Monthly Data Export function does **not** back up metadata configuration files. For metadata, you should be using a source code repository (e.g. [Git](https://git-scm.com/)). This allows you to recover changes to your fields, objects, classes, static resources, and anything else you want to back up configuration-wise. You can even use [SFDX](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/sfdxcli) to make it easier to migrate changes between orgs.